# How to retrieve the value of a variable in a jsp page to another

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a variable declared in one jsp page. This variable is an array.
How can I retrieve this array in the next jsp page.
The code is likely to be:

```
<% 
    String[] a=new String[10];
    int i=0;
    while(resultSet.next())//here I'd retrieved the values from the Database
    {
        a[i]=resultSet.getString(1);
        i++;
    }
%>
```

now i have to retrieve this array a on the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the session, which is an object shared among all pages and servlets of the web application:

```
session.setAttribute("myarray", a);
```

And retrieve it with:

```
String[] bubi = (String[]) session.getAttribute("myarray");
```

Instead if with

> next page

you mean the page that will be included in current page some lines after, you could also use request attributes (not parameters!), setting:

```
request.setAttribute("myarray", a);
```

and getting:

```
String[] bubi = (String[]) request.getAttribute("myarray");
```

Comment: Thank you! It is quite helpfull to me.

Answer (score 0):

each jsp file live for itself. You have two options:
- You use an object class, that can store that in the current session
- You store the array in thehead of the request with `rqeuest.setAttribute("myArgumentName", myArrayObject);`

Answer (score 0):

- store it in the session
- output it in a hidden field, comma-separated, submit it, and recreate the array on the next page

I prefer the 2nd approach.

But try to avoid java code in jsp pages. [See here how and why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)